# How can I add variables together in a sort function? | Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to add two variables together? Example if you have 10 Cash and 10 Bank Money then it should add them together and it's 20 but I want this in a sort function. I did everything but everything seem not to work. This is my code
.

```
Model.find({}).sort({ Money: 'descending' + Bankmoney: 'descending'}).exec(function(err, total) { . . . }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Model.find({}).sort({ Money: -1, Bankmoney: -1}).exec(function(err, total) { . . . }
```

You can find more info here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-sort

Comment: No. It's not working. It does not add each other. I think it does but it does in the wrong way. If my friend has 8 money and 10 bank money, he is top 1, and i'm at 10 money and 23 bank money and then i'm at the top 2.

Comment: Can you try this out?: `sort([['Money', -1], ['Bankmoney', -1]])`

Comment: I already fixed it with another variable though. I still can try it.